# How to Auto remove closing tags

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there's a plugin that when u delete the opening tag eg `<div>` the closing tag is removed too `</div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, yes, there is a plugin called **Emmet**, installed by default in VSCode, that allow you to remove both tags at the same time.

You just need to put the cursor in the tag that you want to remove and, in Command Palette, choose (or write) `Emmet: Remove Tag`

[image]

It removes both tags.
And for sure, you can assign a keybinding shortcut to do it more quickly. Following instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)